# Problem in importing UMAP while importing bertopic

Tags: python, machine-learning, topic-modeling

So everything worked fine with my code and then suddenly the hdbscan was not working anymore, than I re-instaled all packages and now I have a problem with umap.

I did what was suggested here and in other foruns and uninstalled and re-installed both `umap-learn` and `bertopic` . I can import umap as `import umap` or `import umap.umap_ as UMAP` , the problem is when I import bertopic. I tried:

```
import bertopic
```

and

```
import umap.umap_ as UMAP
import bertopic
```

and

```
import umap
import bertopic
```

and

```
import umap
from bertopic import BERTopic
```

and finally:

```
import umap.umap_ as UMAP
from bertopic import BERTopic
```

In all situations, the problem occurs when I'm importing bertopic: `ImportError: cannot import name 'UMAP' from 'umap' (unknown location)` .  I also reboot the machine a several times.  I don't think that issue is related to the environment, because I have been using the same environment before when the same code was working: Python 3.10.7 and Visual Code Studio 1.74.3 . The bertopic is version  0.13.0 and umap-learn version 0.5.3

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution at least for my case: despite the fact that I uninstalled `umap-learn` , there was still a umap folder in the package directory ( c:\python310\lib\site-packages ). I manually deleted the umap folder and later I just installed the bertopic. It works now!

Answer (score 0):

Worked through this today, so posting here in case its of use to anyone. Following the advice here: https://github.com/MaartenGr/BERTopic/issues/1209

Take the following steps:

1. Delete your current virtual environment
2. Create a fresh environment
3. Run `pip install bertopic` from within that new environment

If you now run pip install umap-learn you will be told that all the requirements are already satisfied. Now you can just import as you like using:

```
import umap.umap_ as UMAP
```

All calls to UMAP now need to follow this structure: `UMAP.UMAP`

Answer (score 0):

`pip uninstall umap`

`pip unstall umap-learn`

Wipe out all folders of `umap` and `umap-learn` in your `/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.11.7/lib/python3.11/site-packages` folder

Shutdown your jupyter kernel (if applicable) and re-run your code.